# What does it mean "the course of evolution" in the following context?

Tags: word-meaning

I've read the following context which mentions the word "course of evolution" and I don't think that the meaning is in the simple meaning of course, like a course in the university. It seems to me something like "part of time" or period, but I am not sure even though I checked the definition in the [dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/course), but to be honest it's not clear to me (probably because I'm non Native English speaker)

> "Our starting point for exploring the nervous system is the neuron, a
>   cell type exemplifying the close fit of form and function that often
>   **arises over the course of evolution**"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In LDOCE, one of the senses concerns *development* which is singular and is *the usual or natural way that something changes, develops, or is done* as in,

> forces that shape the course of evolution
>
> Meeting Sally changed the whole course of his life.

Although the collocation that has been used for *course* in your example is *over*. *Course* in the sense of *a period of time or process during which something happens* normally collocates with **during/in/throughout/over** as in,

> Over the course of the next few years, the steel industry was reorganized.